# I can't delete events on Google Calendar in PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to delete an event on my Google Calendar but my method is not working.I am still new to php and Google Calendars and don't understand it. Here is my php function:

```
private function __calendarEventDelete($params) {
        $cal = new _gCal();
        $cal->gCal->calendarService->events->delete('primary', $params->data->OrderConfirmationId);
        var_dump($cal->gCal->calendarService->events->delete('primary', $events->data->OrderConfirmationId));                     
 }
```

Comment: add three spaces before the `private function` part.

Comment: I have added three spaces before the private function but it's not working..do I have to create an event inside this function? please help

Comment: I was referring to the formatting of the question.it's been fixed now.i'm not familiar with the Google Calender API.have you [read the docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete#try-it) ? make sure you have required authorization as well.also you might wanna add any error messages you are getting to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar switched to their v3 API which requires you to authenticate using OAuth 2. Settings this up is far from trivial, but here goes:

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console.](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Select a project.
3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the Calendar API
4. In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials.
5. Click on Create New Client ID
6. Set up service account and click on OKAY
7. Use this service account and it's generated key file to have your app communicate with Google Calendar

There is loads more to figure out, but this should get you started!